# How to return the derived type from base method

Tags: c#, class, return, radix, derived

For better understanding, here is what I would like to do:

```
Dog dog = Animal.Color("Red").Paw(4); 
Bird bird = Animal.Color("Blue").Wing(1);
```

With the below code I could do the following:

```
Dog dog = Animal.Paw(4).Color("Red"); 
Bird bird = Animal.Wing(1).Color("Blue");
```

But I would like to do it the first way.

Here is my code design so far:

```
public class Animal 
{
    public static string color = "";

    public Animal Color( string _color )
    {
        color = _color;

        return this.GetType() ;
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal 
{
    public static int pawNumber = 0;

    public static Dog Paw( int _pawNumber )
    {
        pawNumber = _pawNumber;

        return this;
    }
}

public class Bird : Animal 
{
    public static int wingNumber = 0;

    public Bird Wing( int _wingNumber )
    {
        wingNumber = _wingNumber;

        return this;
    }
}
```

So, basically, it's not working because Color is typed as Animal, even if I return this.GetType() ( which gives me the right type ) , the return value is not typed as needed.

Hope I was clear enough and that somebody can help me!

Comment: Your code sample is kind of nonsense because you have static methods returning `this`, and there is no `this` in a static method. And returning `this.GetType()` is compounded nonsense since the return type is `Animal`, there is no `this`, and `GetType()` would return a `Type` object. However, I don't think you want any of this anyway. Explain your actual problem a bit better, but I think you might need to consider an `AnimalFactory` class with method names such as `CreateDog`, `CreateBird`, etc. (`Animal` itself shouldn't be concerned with derived classes.)

Comment: Sorry about static everywhere, I badly rewrited it from my code. I'm new to this.

Regarding what I'm trying to achieve, it's exactly as said in the beginning of the question

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. I'm assuming you are coming from a functional language background in which there are not states or variables and each call is the result of another. This is not the case in object-oriented languages. In OO, a method should return a value that makes sense in the context of its body. In your case, you call `Paw()` to set a private field, but there is no need to return the instance object _since you already have access to it_ in the caller method (i.e. the `dog` variable). Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: visual studio itself showing the error with your code.

Comment: The idea is that all animal have some things in common, but they also have some specific attribute. I'd like to set some of the attribute as I like. So returning "this" allow me to do something like:
Animal.Color("red").Paw(3).Aggressivity("Low").Tail("Short").

Where Color and Aggressivity are from Base Class ( Animal ) and Paw and Tail from the Derived Class. 

Then, Color, Aggressivity, Paw, Tail, are all optional, and I can call them the order I want, not a specific one.

Comment: @albertobrendo You can still achieve that by having different calls (`dog.Color("red"); dog.Paw(3); etc.` or eventually making those properties, which is the more standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. It's really ugly but does what you ask.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog().Color("Red").Paw(4);
        Bird bird = new Bird().Color("Blue").Wing(1);
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    private string color = "";
    public Animal Color(string _color)
    {
        color = _color;
        return this;
    }
}

public abstract class ChainingAnimal<T> : Animal
    where T : Animal
{
    public T Color(string _color)
    {
        return (T)base.Color(_color);
    }
}

public class Dog : ChainingAnimal<Dog>
{
    private int pawNumber = 0;
    public Dog Paw(int _pawNumber)
    {
        pawNumber = _pawNumber;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Bird : ChainingAnimal<Bird>
{
    private int wingNumber = 0;
    public Bird Wing(int _wingNumber)
    {
        wingNumber = _wingNumber;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it considered as ugly, but it's working exactly as needed. Thank you for taking the time to answer and most of all, trying to understand my question. For better understanding and knowledge, could you tell me what keywords I should type on Google to learn more about this syntax?

Comment: The syntax you were trying to achieve is called 'method chaining'. It's much more cumbersome to get that to work well when you also want inheritance, but as you can see it is possible. I call it ugly because you need another class 'ChainingAnimal' to be able to re-use the functionality of the Animal class. It's okay in this example, but imagine that you are going to go further with your class hierachy, e.g. inherit Bulldog from Dog. You would then need a ChainingDog to get Bulldog to have the Dog functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.

As my understanding, you want `Animal.Color("Red")` to return a `Dog` instance in the first line.
But then, you want `Animal.Color("Blue")` to return a `Bird` instance.

You literally want the compiler to guess which one of these two instances its going to return to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell **exactly** what it is you're trying to do - and I'll note that trying to build an inheritance hierarchy where the base class knows the details of the subclasses is a recipe for pain and suffering. I also don't understand why having paws would make an animal a Dog while having wings makes it a Bird; Cats and Bats would beg to differ.

That said, something along these lines will do what it **appears** you're trying to accomplish, which is to have static methods in the base class that allow creating instances of known subclasses with the parameters in different orders:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Color { get; private set; }
    public Animal(string color)
    {
        this.Color = color;
    }

    // These static methods **really** should be in a separate
    // factory class
    public static Bird CreateBird(string color, int wings)
    {
        return new Bird(color, wings);
    }
    public static Bird CreateBird(int wings, string color)
    {
        return new Bird(color, wings);
    }
    public static Dog CreateDog(string color, int paws)
    {
        return new Dog(color, paws);
    }
    public static Dog CreateDog(int paws, string color)
    {
        return new Dog(color, paws);
    }
}
public class Bird : Animal
{
    public int Wings { get; private set; }
    public Bird(string color, int wings)
        : base(color)
    {
        this.Wings = wings;
    }
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public int Paws { get; private set; }
    public Dog(string color, int paws)
        : base(color)
    {
        this.Paws = paws;
    }
}
```

Usage would be along these lines:

```
public void OneCodeSample()
{
    Dog dog = Animal.CreateDog("Red", 4);
    Bird bird = Animal.CreateBird("Blue", 1);
    // do something useful...
}
public void AnotherCodeSample()
{
    Dog dog = Animal.CreateDog(4, "Red");
    Bird bird = Animal.CreateBird(1, "Blue");
    // do something else useful...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But I said in the comments. I wanted to avoid the multi arguments methods and prefers multi optionnal methods. Can be found as ugly and whatsoever but fullfilling my needs.

Answer (score -1):

You should return `this` and not `this.GetType()`. Result of the latter is of type `Type`

Comment: If I return this, I get the error: Type "Animal" does not contain a definition for "Paw" and no extension method "Paw" of type "Animal" could be found